# luabind did not launch the function i had defined to it

Tags: c++, scripting, lua, luabind

In a class called Test_Class, I have a function :

```
shoot_a_bullet(int damage)  
{
    cout << "runned"; // i had #using namespace std
}
```

I had defined the code like following

```
luabind::module(myLuaState)[
    luabind::def("shoot_a_bullet", &Test_Class::shoot_a_bullet)
];
```

And follow code didn't give me an output on screen

```
luaL_dostring(myLuaState,"shoot_a_bullet(134)\n");
```

PS:I did put cin.get() at the end, that's not the problem.

edit:
    My main purpose of doing this is to let my scripted Character/Enemies able to directly adding stuff to a vector that hold bullets/effect/enemies and ect.
    The reason i can't make the function static is because i need the pointer of main game stage to let it work.

following codes works fine

```
void print_hello(int number) {
    cout << "hello world and : " << number << endl << "number from main : " << x << endl;
}

int x; //and the main with a global value

int main()
{
    cin >> x;
    lua_State *myLuaState = luaL_newstate();

luabind::open(myLuaState);

luabind::module(myLuaState)[
    luabind::def("print_hello", print_hello)
];

luaL_dostring(
    myLuaState,
    "print_hello(123)\n"
    );
cin.get();
cin.get();

lua_close(myLuaState);
}
```

I need a way to do this in a class that's not main

Comment: Is the `shoot_a_bullet` function declared in the class or outside?

Comment: try printing out the error. You might have another problem

Comment: @Dmitry Ledentsov there is no error

Comment: @Mohammed Majeed: i did declared that inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't register member functions like this. What your are doing is like the following in C++:

```
Test_Class::shoot_a_bullet(134);
```

MSVC for example calls that "illegal call of non-static member function", and that's exactly what it is.

Look at the section [Binding classes to Lua](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#binding-classes-to-lua) in the Luabind documentation for how to bind a class to Lua. You then need to create an object of this class and call the function on it e.g. with `myobject:shoot_a_bullet(134)` in Lua (the `:` being syntactic sugar for passing `myobject` as first argument).

To see the error, you should first check the return value of [`luaL_dostring`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_dostring). If it returns `true`, the call failed. The message is pushed onto the Lua stack as as string, accessible with

```
lua_tostring(myLuaState, -1);
```

In this case it should be something like

```
No matching overload found, candidates:
void shoot_a_bullet(Test_Class&)
```

Explanation: When you register a member function as a free one, luabind adds an extra reference parameter at the front so that the method is actually called on the argument object passed for it.

Comment: one needs to make sure if the author didn't make the member static

Comment: Now some thing bothers me even worse, because it returned true, and still no output

Comment: `true` does mean that an error occurred (whereas `false` would mean success). It's a bit counterintuitive. See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_dostring